# mysql too long query

Tags: mysql, subquery

i have a problem with this mysql query. It take vmore as 1 day to execute ...

The query is :

```
INSERT INTO traduction  
(traduction.`id`,traduction.`traduction`,traduction.`language`,traduction.`type`) 
(
 SELECT cities.id,cities.name, '', 'city' FROM cities 
  WHERE cities.id NOT IN 
   (
    SELECT traduction.`id` FROM traduction WHERE traduction.type='city' GROUP BY id
   )
);
```

I made a explain extended on the 2 select and it says DEPENDENT SUBQUERY so the second select is played for every select on cities but I think it's useless.

There is a way in mysql or another sql server which can allow that ?

Or maybe a complet other query.

The idea is, if a city doesn't have a traduction, the city name should be writen in the traduction table. Then I just have to look in traduction table and not city table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
INSERT INTO traduction   
(traduction.`id`,traduction.`traduction`,traduction.`language`,traduction.`type`)  
( 
SELECT  cities.id,
        cities.name, 
        '', 
        'city' 
FROM    cities  LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  traduction.`id` 
            FROM    traduction 
            WHERE   traduction.type='city' 
            GROUP BY id 
        ) s ON cities.id = s.id
WHERE   s.ID IS NULL
);
```

Also ensure that you have the correct indexes on your tables, for lets say *traduction.type or traduction.id and cities.id*

```
INSERT INTO traduction   
(traduction.`id`,traduction.`traduction`,traduction.`language`,traduction.`type`)  
( 
SELECT  cities.id,
        cities.name, 
        '', 
        'city' 
FROM    cities  LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    traduction.`id` 
            FROM    traduction 
            WHERE   traduction.type='city'
        ) s ON cities.id = s.id
WHERE   s.ID IS NULL
);
```

EDIT: NOT EXISTS

```
INSERT INTO traduction    
(traduction.`id`,traduction.`traduction`,traduction.`language`,traduction.`type`)   
(  
SELECT  cities.id, 
        cities.name,  
        '',  
        'city'  
FROM    cities 
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT  DISTINCT 
                                traduction.`id`  
                        FROM    traduction  
                        WHERE   traduction.type='city'
                        AND     cities.id = traduction.id 
                    )
);
```

Comment: there is no dependency more but I don't think that it's made that i want.

how can be cities.id = s.id and s.ID IS NULL ?

I can't join because cities.id doen't not exists in the traduction table. I want to create it with this query.

Comment: This query would bring back all items from cities that does not exist in traduction. That is why I mention the **LEFT JOIN and IS NULL** check

Comment: i just run the 2 select and it runs like 1hour ago. Is it normal ? There is 1,200,000 rows in cities and 750,000 in traduction.

Comment: No, this is not normal, do you have indexes on the tables and if so, what indexes do you have?

Comment: cities.id as primary
traduction.traduction,language,type,id as index

Comment: Have you tried changing the group by to a distinct, see edit answer?

Comment: disctinct is a bit faster but the idea is to make the subquery just one time. The select on traduction give 313000 result, I search a way to execute it just one time.

Maybe should i use function/procedure ?

From which edit are u speaking ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Running the query using a sub select, not in the where clause, should be a lot faster.

Comment: I think it's good now.

881711 rows in set (32.31 sec)

The insert should be ok too.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, it's now really faster.

881711 rows affected (4min 14.82 sec)!

But "NOT EXISTS" is almost the same as "cities.id NOT IN" ? Or the problem was just the group by ?

Comment: You wil notice that from the not exists section, there is a link to cities.id in the sub select. this should limit the returned rows for each pass

Comment: Ok that's clever i understand now. Thanks you again. Sorry i don't know very well stackoverflow, should i do something for your reputation ?

Comment: Its fine, you already did by accepting the answer, also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq at the **What is reputation?**

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying traduction table, that's why the results of inner subquery cannot be reused

Comment: there is not a way to force the cache ? Like
(Select * FROM tracution) as traduction_query and then use traduction_query as a list or something like that ...

Maybe I should create a function or procedure ?